# Optimizing a CloudKit sign-in on app launch with error handling. How can I better handle the optional chaining? Swift 3.0/Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Is there a cleaner, swiftier solution to handle the optional chaining happening in my code below? I'm setting up the user for CloudKit access in my custom function runCKsetup():

```
func runCKsetup() {
  container.requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
      if let error = error as? NSError {
        if let errorDictionary: AnyObject = error.userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> as AnyObject? {
          let localizedDescription = errorDictionary["NSLocalizedDescription"]! as! String!
          if localizedDescription! == "This operation has been rate limited" {
          // Create an alert view
          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Network Error", message: localizedDescription!, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Test for Connection", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)  { (action) in
            self.runCKsetup()
          })
          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
          } else {
          // Create an alert view
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign in to iCloud", message: localizedDescription!, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)  { (action) in
          })
          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
    }
    return
  }

  if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.granted {
    self.container.fetchUserRecordID { (recordID, error) in
      guard error == nil else {
        self.presentMessageAlert((error?.localizedDescription)!, title: "Error", buttonTitle: "Ok")
        return }
      guard let recordID = recordID else { return }

      self.container.discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: recordID, completionHandler: { (info, fetchError) in
        //do something with the users names: e.g. print("\(info?.nameComponents?.givenName) \(info?.nameComponents?.familyName)")
      })
    }
  }
}
```

}